# Axios Filter table returns counts but not data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, chart.js, axios

I am currently working on ASP.Net MVC project. I am using Vuejs- Axios to get out data from entity data models. So...axios.get (gets the API) and now I am displaying my chart based on the value received.I am also on the same page showing table of data(same api results). The table has a search box, as user enter details to search a particular product my chart should show respective data. The problem is : I am in my javascript for table data: created api request , computed and used method(for filtering data). Now in the same filter method...when I do console.log(response.length)...I get correct filtered records....but when I write response.data….I get msg as undefined...

Kindly let a beginner like me know...how I can use this filtered data to create new chart...

If the filtered data can show correct length...it should be able to show data as well..

Thanks.

Edited: code here...

```
Javascript for chart( Vue-Chartjs):

var app = new Vue({
el:"#abc"
data:{
chart:null,
loading:false
},
created function(){
this.loading = true

axios.get('api/Work')
.then (function(response){
console.log(response.data)

calculated fields required.....

var ctx= document.getElementById("chart1")
chart....labels, datasets..etc....



Javascript - Loading table)

var app = new Vue({
el:"#abcd",
data(){
return:
fields:[
]},
created function(){

axios.get('api/Work')
.then (function(response){
console.log(response.data)
},
computed:{
mounted(){
this.totalrows= this.totalrows.length
}
},
methods:{
onfiltered(filteritems){

console.log(filteritems.length) =====returns correct table search  - i.e filtered table length.....
console.log(filteritems.data)
```

=====returns undefined...........Stuck up here......

Once I get the filtered data , I can make the new chart based on the filtered values. So this is the place where I need clarifications.

Thanks.

Comment: Very kindly, without showing any code, we have no chance of understanding your problem. Please consider creating a [mcve] in the question itself (or in codesandbox.io, or similar, if you need a multi-file system). In current form your question is not answerable.

Comment: can you share your code please?